# Does the power of a bounded sequence remain bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be an open bounded domain and let $(u_n)_n\subset W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ be a bounded sequence in $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$, $1<p<N$.
My question is: it is possible to conclude that also
$$\| |u_n|^s u_n\|_{W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)}<+\infty?$$
(here $s>0$)

Could anyone please help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: May I ask you what book are you using for this? I am just curious.

Comment: Sun, no books, just a paper I am trying to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is NO. The function
$$f(x):=\frac{\chi_{[0,1]}(x)}{x^{\frac{1-\epsilon}{p}}}$$
is bounded in $L^p$ for every $\epsilon>0$. But we can find $\epsilon>0$ such that $f^s \notin L^{p}$ for every $s>1$.
Similarly the function
$$g(x):=\frac{\chi_{[1,\infty[}(x)}{x^{\frac{1+\epsilon}{p}}}$$
is bounded in $L^p$ for every $\epsilon>0$. But we can find $\epsilon>0$ such that $f^s \notin L^{p}$ for every $s<1$.

To get examples in $W^{1,p}$ simply replace the characteristic functions with smooth cutoff functions.